# How to make letter with some overhead

Tags: accents

How do I make the following in a TeX file? I try a lot of things but still don't work.

[image]

Comment: See Table 17 (Text-mode Accents, p 14) of the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `\'e`. But make sure to read http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes